# Magento 2 OAuth API - Consumer key has expired

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.2, oauth

I've created an integration in `System->Extensions->Integrations` and allowed all access.

[image]

I'm using Postman to test the API, but I'm getting error:

> Consumer key has expired.

I've tried `cache:clear, setup:upgrade, reauthorising` the integration

[image]

Comment: magento ver 1.9.2.3,I am work with REST API in POSTMAN, i have all oAuth 1.0 details like Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Token Secret. Now i moved to oAuth 2.0, how can i get my all oAuth 2.0 details? @Aasim Goriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though Magento 2.2.3 has a Bug:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13961